# Problems with javascript / window.confirm function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coldfusion-11

I have an HTML button that calls the `checkTax()` function.
The function should either confirm and proceed with the form submit when OK is clicked, or cancel the submission and redirect the user to a different page.

This is the function:

```
function checkTax () {
    if ( CUSTTAXRATE == 0 ) {
        var r = confirm("Your current tax rate is 0.\n\nIf this is correct click OK to continue.\n\nIf this needs to be adjusted, click CANCEL and visit the quote set up page under DEALER RESOURCES tab.");
        if (r == true){
            return true;
        }
        else {
        <!---   return false; --->
             window.location.replace("index.cfm?action=retailQuote.settings");

        }
    }

}
```

I have tried both just cancelling the submission or redirecting it, but I cant get either to work. Both ways still submit the form and proceed.
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What code do you use to call this function. Can you show that please?

Comment: For reference, JS uses `//` for single line comments. You're including HTML comments, which could break your script.

Comment: Related: [How to prevent form from being submitted?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3350247/4642212)

Comment: This is my button. <input type="Submit" value="Save Quote" class="hidden-print btn printButton btn-danger btn-lg" onClick="checkTax() ">
Sorry about the commenting. I write in coldfusion and I was just trying to show both of the ways that I have tried.

Comment: If this is used in the form's `onsubmit` attribute, make sure it's called as `onsubmit="return checkTax()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use a `return` statement in the button's `onclick` attribute.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="return checkTax();">Submit</button>
```

Otherwise, the return value from the function will be ignored, and it won't prevent the form from submitting when it returns `false`.

Comment: That is what I was doing wrong. I needed to add the "return" into the onClick. Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried completing the answers above for your simplification.
Please find the code below :

```
<body>
<form action="">
    <input type=text id="t1">
    <button type="submit" onclick="return checkTax();">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTax() {
        var CUSTTAXRATE = document.getElementById("t1");
        if (CUSTTAXRATE == 0) {
            var r = confirm("Your current tax rate is 0.\n\nIf this is correct click OK to continue.\n\nIf this needs to be adjusted, click CANCEL and visit the quote set up page under DEALER RESOURCES tab.");
            if (r == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                window.location
                        .replace("index.cfm?action=retailQuote.settings");
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```